# ifthen: Replacing a single character in a fixed environment with a longer string

Tags: conditionals

We use a custom command to highlight system properties:

```
\newcommand{\propDesc}[2]{
\fcolorbox{white}{propbg}{
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\vspace{1ex}
\textcolor{title}{#1}
\\
#2 
\vspace{1ex}
\end{minipage}
}
\\
}
```

The title (#1) is highlighted in blue (emphasized). The description (#2) is plain text.
Most of these properties include a `_` which is manually replaced by a `\_`. So, a some`_`property becomes some`\_`property in order to be compiled. This is pretty annoying. 
 My goal is to find a way that allows my to replace all `_` automatically whithout having to change the existing `\_`. Thus, i simply use copy&paste to add a new property. Something like if `_` then `\_`, otherwise do nothin or simply `\_`. 
If been working with some basic ifthen commands. However, I am not able to find/ program a command that will get the job done. I need a command that will replace all `_` \propDesc command without beeing disturbed by the existing `\_`

Comment: Can you include a before/after case for different situation? `xstring` can do this conveniently

Answer (score 2):

You could replace `_` by `\_` but it's probably simpler to make `_` work.

Also you have multiple extra spaces which will generate overfull boxes or anomolous vertical spacing as they have to fit on the same line as the `\textwidth` box.

```
\newcommand{\propDesc}[2]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fcolorbox{white}{propbg}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{1ex}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textcolor{title}{#1}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#2%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \par% always put \par or a blank line before vspace
\vspace{1ex}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{minipage}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\% almost certainly should be `\par` `\\ ` other than in tables is usually wrong.
}
```

To fix the `_` issue something like

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\propDesc{\begingroup\catcode`\_=12 % make _ a normal character
\newcommand{\xpropDesc}[2]{\endgroup%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fcolorbox{white}{propbg}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}%%%%%%%%%%%%
\vspace{1ex}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textcolor{title}{#1}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
#2%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \par% always put \par or a blank line before vspace
\vspace{1ex}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{minipage}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\% almost certainly should be `\par` `\\ ` other than in tables is usually wrong.
}
```

If you need a subscript in math within one of the arguments you can't use `_` so you'd have to use `\sb`.

Comment: Your approach looks promissing, but why/ how do I use `\newcommand{\xpropDesc}[2]{\endgroup`? There is no `}` linked to it. I basically inheritted our documentclass and know most, but not all of its features. So far, the propDesc command does not refere to math.